# ajax_url is not defined. Any ideas on how to fix?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, url

I have tried going through all of the posts to do with the URL not being defined however none have fixed it.

My code in index:

```
   wp_enqueue_script('BbingoAppG', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/formProcess.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 0.1, false);
   wp_localize_script( 'BbingoAppG', 'bbingo2_obj', array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ));
```

Then lower down:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_bsetter_ajax_request', 'bsetter_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_bsetter_ajax_request', 'bsetter_ajax_request' );
```

The function being called:

```
function submitCard(newPartner){
         alert(newPartner);
         jQuery.ajax({
          url: ajax_url, // Since WP 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined and points to admin-ajax.php
          data: {
              'action':'bsetter_ajax_request', // This is our PHP function below
              'gamecard': JSON.stringify(newPartner)
          },
          success:function(data) {
      // This outputs the result of the ajax request (The Callback)
                alert("Successfully added a partner");
              jQuery("#newPForm").text(data);
          },
          error: function(errorThrown){
              window.alert(errorThrown);
          }
      });

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `bbingo2_obj.ajax_url`

Answer (score 0):

if ajax url is not defined it might be because your JS script is called before it is declared. Make sure to add your JS in your functions.php with the [wp_register_script hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/).

> If you want a quick fix or test the ajax endpoint, the base url is `/admin-ajax.php?action=bsetter_ajax_request`.

`function.php`

```php
// exemple
function my_enqueue_scripts()
{
    wp_register_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/myscript.js' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: This is not why.  It's because he called the wrong `ajax_url`

Comment: Thanks alot guys, managed to get it fixed with your help.